# This code works on chrome but not on firefox and IE or Safari, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this code... it works fine on Google chrome, but firefox and EI and Safari, keeps poping the alert over and over again. What should i add to make sure the alert goes only once.

```
<html>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--

        document.onclick = myClickHandler;


        function myClickHandler() {
            alert("All orders require minimum two weeks notice before your event");
        }
        -->

        $(function() {
            $(document).on('click.once', function() {
                alert("Thank you for your visit. Happy shopping!!");
                $(document).off('click.once');
            })
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: What about using one()?

Comment: Create a global variable (outside the function) and set it =0, once clicked set it as 1, then test if the variable is >0, don't do the alert. I think that only Chrome can understand the "click.once" event.

Comment: @RocKhalil namespaced events are supported on all browsers

Comment: $(function () {
  $(document).one('click', function () {
      alert("Thank you for your visit. Happy shopping!!");
  })}); try this

Comment: *"keeps poping the alert over and over again."* Which one? There are two. The code seems to work perfectly fine in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/x6gmk93p/

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments... I am referring on both alerts. in Firefox and IE... every time the check the box to prevent more dialog to appear. it keeps showing. i will try prabhu option...

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', function() {
            alert("Thank you for your visit. Happy shopping!!");
            $(document).unbind('click');
        })
  });
```

Comment: thank you. i actually tried this option, but for some reason the alerts keep popping up at every click in firefox... and ie... in chrome still working fine. I'm not sure what could being wrong...

Comment: maybe you should use  /* */    install of   <!--  -->     . the first one  will pop the alert over and over again  ,  and the second one works fine  on  my safari firefox and chrome